# How to define multiple serializers in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Say, I publish and consume different type of java objects.For each I have to define own serializer implementations. 
How can we provide all implementations in the kafka consumer/producer properties file under the "serializer.class" property?

Comment: Do you insist on doing this 'properties only'? In our case we just use `ByteArrayDeserializer` and do the real deserialization in the Java code, depending on topic.

Comment: @Harald   No, im a newbie..I try to find a suitable way to implement this..I got advise from kafka user list to use avro schemas..I try to find a better solution. I plan to use different topics for each type of object. (number of object types= number of topics)..
So, I need deserializers/serializers= topics = number of objects.

What would be the better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a similar setup with different objects in different topics, but always the same object type in one topic. We use the [`ByteArrayDeserializer`](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html) that comes with the Java API 0.9.0.1, which means or message consumers get only ever a `byte[]` as the value part of the message (we consistently use `String` for the keys). The first thing the topic-specific message consumer does is to call the right deserializer to convert the `byte[]`.  You could use a [apache commons helper class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html). Simple enough.

If you prefer to let the `KafkaConsumer` do the deserialization for you, you can of course write your own [`Deserializer`](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html). The `deserialize` method you need to implement has the topic as the first argument. Use it as a key into a map that provides the necessary deserializer and off you go. My hunch is that in most cases you will just do a normal Java deserialization anyway.

The downside of the 2nd approach is that you need a common super class for all your message objects to be able to parameterize the `ConsumerRecord<K,V>` properly. With the first approach, however, it is `ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>` anyway. But then you convert the `byte[]` to the object you need just at the right place and need only one cast right there.

Comment: Is there any common serializer/deserializer available for kafka 0.8.x version?

Comment: The 0.8 de-/serializers for Java are described here: https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html, so there is nothing general. But as mentioned in my answer, you can just use normal Java de-/serialization to create/restore from `byte[]` or the apache commons helper class.

Answer (score 2):

One option is **[Avro](http://avro.apache.org)**. Avro lets you define record types that you can then easily serialize and deserialize.

Here's an example schema adapted from the documentation:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number", "default": null, "type": ["null","int"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "default": null, "type": ["null","string"]}
 ]
}
```

Avro distinguishes between so-called `SpecificData` and `GenericData`. With `SpecificData` readers and writers, you can easily serialize and deserialize known Java objects. The downside is `SpecificData` requires compile-time knowledge of the class to schema conversion.

On the other hand, `GenericData` readers and writers let you deal with record types you didn't know about at compile time. While obviously very powerful, this can get kind of clumsy -- you will have to invest time coding around the rough edges.

There are other options out there -- `Thrift` comes to mind -- but from what I understand, one of the major differences is Avro's ability to work with `GenericData`.

Another benefit is multi-language compatibility. Avro I know has native support for a lot of languages, on a lot of platforms. The other options do too, I am sure -- probably any off the shelf option is going to be better than rolling your own in terms of multi-language support, it's just a matter of degrees.