# Good practice to send different message types in order, to Kafka

Tags: java, python, architecture, apache-kafka

Beginner in Kafka.

I would like having a python producer sending first several messages (json) of type A, then of type B. The java consumer must consume them in keeping this order with the aim of updating a database.

My first thought was to use a single topic to guarantee the order of the messages. I read these answers :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37056589/8454889
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587402

Yet it seems that it's not a good practice in Kafka to use one topic for different object types ?

So another solution more "kafkaesque" is having two topics for this problem. But is there a way for the producer to be sure that all the messages in the first topic have been consumed before sending on the second topic ? Will I lose the asynchronism ?

In your opinion, what is the best strategy in this type of configuration ?

Thank you.

Comment: do all events of B have to be read after A or some vents ob B can be read after some events of A ?

Comment: Thanks for your question @marvel308. Ideally, all events of B after all events of A.

Answer (score 8):

The order is not preserved across multiple topics or multiple partitions so you need to send all your messages to one topic and one partition within that topic.

Don't worry about sending different data types to the same topic unless you are using Avro or some other serializer that enforces a consistent schema per topic. If you are sending JSON then a single topic is fine.

It's important to note that order is not preserved across multiple partitions of a topic. If your topic has a single partition then you are fine. If your topic has more than one partition then you should use a key when you publish and use the same key for all messages that need to stay in order. This will ensure they all go to the same partition.

If you want to be really sure the order is preserved you should set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`. Otherwise, an error and retry of one message might put it out of order from the other in-flight messages.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Hans. I've chosen a JsonDeserializer for the value deserializer of my Java/Spring consumer. And I've wrapped the payload in an object which contains the "type" to know how to cast the value into the good Object type in my receiver.

Comment: Order is only maintained in a partition. First sentence makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: Revised for less confusion